# python - join list elements in every possilble way

Tags: python, string, list

I need to join list like `x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and make another list of every possible joins for example `['a'], ['aa'],...['dcbbaa']`

Answer (score 3):

Try `itertools.permutations`:

```py
from itertools import permutations

x = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d"]

for i in range(1, len(x) + 1):
    for p in permutations(x, i):
        print("".join(p))
```

Prints:

```
a
a
b
b
c
d
aa
ab
ab
ac

...

dcbaab
dcbaba
dcbaab
dcbaba
dcbbaa
dcbbaa
```